# Iterating Objects in a collection and calling methods on specific objects

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection of objects in a list.

The base class is `car`, the derived classes are `Compact`, `Truck` and `SUV`.

On my base class I have a method called `Drive()`.

Lets say I have 10 cars in my list and car #3 is a truck that I want to run the `Drive()` function on. How do I select that specific object from my list and run the method on it?

Comment: Why would you want to call the base method explicitly? That reeks of bad design.

Comment: That's interesting. Why bad design? Drive() might be a general method, suitable for most inherited classes, bar a few that have specialisation.

Comment: If the method is override then obviously I want the overriden method. I am new to OO Programming so I apologize if I used the wrong term.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. The runtime will detect the Type to be Truck, and call the overridden method. If the method is not overriding, but shadowing, THEN casting to the base type will work.

Comment: @CryptoJones aha, that's fine. You can use my answer below, then.

Comment: Although this not a very good class hierarchy, but I suspect this is just an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Car> carList;
// fill List with values
carList[2].Drive();
```

Comment: Dumb question; If wanted to print out the index # of the car that I am driving, how do I do that?

Comment: @CryptoJones `carList.IndexOf(myCar)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
// Add cars....
car[2].Drive();
```

Comment: This will still call the derived method

Comment: So you want to call the base method without executing in in the derived class? I don't think this is possible (any why would you do this?)

Comment: Yeah, if there was a method override I would have wanted that. I apologize for mispeaking. Thank You for taking the time to answer.